# How can I set up Xdebug in PhpStorm to listen only in one browser?

Tags: php, magento, phpstorm, magento2, xdebug

I've set up Xdebug in PhpStorm for debugging Magento 2. I've made zero configuration and configuration with server listening. I've got Xdebug extension in Firefox and Chrome browsers.

My problem is when I enter my Magento 2 page I got incoming connection to PhpStorm and everything works fine but when I open the same page in both Firefox and Chrome PhpStorm will start debugging even if I turn off debug in browser extension.

How can I configure Xdebug in PhpStorm to listen only in one browser? Bacause it is annoying when I want to open a page normally and turn on debug mode in PhpStorm. Can you help me?

Comment: Looks like you have xdebug.remote_autostart enabled. Try disabling it, see more at https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Comment: In addition to the above: if the aforementioned setting is set correctly to `0`, it's possible that the Xdebug cookie is still there in browser. In such case, delete all cookies for that site in the browser where you do not want to have debugging triggered.

Comment: After added line xdebug.remote_autostart=0 i can open debug in one browser and in second browser normally! That's great! Thank you!